# How to restore a specific folder in Eclipse SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I deleted a /common folder from the root directory of my SVN store and it turns out I need it... problem is I can't figure out how to just restore that one folder.

This folder is on a specific version.... I don't want to restore all changes on that version, just this specific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `replace with latest from repository` the parent map via Eclipse SVN options. That will automatically restore the map. If this doesn't work, be more specific about the situation please, i.e. structure and why can't you just revert?

Comment: If nothing works you can at least checkout the revision that had the map in another location and copy the content and commit it ;), but it has to be possible, will edit when found an answer.

Comment: You can use `svn co http://my_repository_site.com/location/path/to/specific/map -r <good revision>` to check out only that specific map, will make it less time and memory consuming :)

Answer (score 1):

Go into Synchronize View (Window -> View -> Other -> Team/Synchronize). There you can right click on the deleted folder and tell Subversion to revert.

Comment: Do this to select which revision to compare to, Right click on root svn folder, choose history, find the desired revision, right click and choose compare.

Answer (score 1):

While it's all about the command line, the below link should help you understand what you need to do with Subclipse or Subversive (you didn't specify which client for eclipse you were using).  Basically you going to need to do a reverse merge.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect